# Extraindo dados com Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Eu fiz um script Python para acessar o site do TJ-SP para fazer uma determinada pesquisa e fazer um Web Scraping com o resultado da pesquisa.

esse é o HTML:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu quero pegar o texto que esta contido nessa tag: `<span class>1009238445480</span> ==$0`, só que o elemento `class` não possui nenhum valor

também tem outras partes do HTML que contem isso: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tem a tag `<span class="labelClass">Área:</span> Cível`,
nessa tag eu preciso pegar o valor `Cível`

tem a tag `<span id class>Perdas e danos</span>`

`id class` não contem nenhum valor

também tenho outra tag:

```
<td valign> ==$0
    <span id class>R$ 245,00</span>
</td>
```

preciso capturar o valor `R$ 245,00`

aqui está meu script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
from time import sleep

URL = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do'
user = 'x0x0x0x0x0x0x'
password ='x0x0x0x0x0x0x'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URL)

browser.find_element_by_id('login').click()
browser.find_element_by_name('user').send_keys(user)
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id('Enviar').click()

browser.find_element_by_id('NUMB').send_keys('1009238445480')
browser.find_element_by_id('Enviar_').click()

scrap = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

processo = scrap.find('span', {'class':' '' '})
print(processo)
```

aqui eu estou tentando pegar o valor da tag: `<span class>1009238445480</span> ==$0`

```
processo = scrap.find('span', {'class':' '' '})
    print(processo)
```

então ele me retorna:

> None

alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu web crawler está na direção certa. Acontece que você está errando na maneira de buscar os elementos, acredito que esteja errando por **falta de conhecimento teórico**. **Então vamos a um pouco de teoria**!

A varias formas de se trabalhar com linguagens de Marcação (*HTML, XML*) são bons exemplos.

As ferramentas que trabalham com HTML e XML tem varias formas de buscar os elementos dentro deste ramo vamos citar algumas formas interessantes para você.

Mais Conhecidos:

- CSS-selector
- TAG-selector
- ATRIBUTE-selector
- Xpath
- DOM Elements

Menos Conhecidos:

- Hierarchy Map
- Semantic Selector
- CSS path

---

No seu caso você usa 
`scrap.find('span', {'class':' '' '})`

vamos detalhar o funcionamento do **find**, em ordem de execução.

1. Pegue todas as tags **span**
2. Encontre todas as tags span que contenham a **class** especifica ''

Bom você percebeu que a class requer um valor e quando você passa '' o find vai tentar pesquisar tags assim:
`<span class="''" >`  ou seja **não vai encontrar nada** !

Mas como então podemos pegar este span especifico, você pode abordar para outras praticas.

---

## Xpath

por exemplo um **Xpath** retorna um caminho até o elemento especifico por exemplo:

**/html/body/div/span** corresponde a

`<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <div>
    <span>
       Elemento Requisitado
    </span>
   </div> 
 </body>
</html>`

Você pode copiar o xpath de um elemento utilizando a ferramenta inspecionar do navegador.

O xpath não é recomendado porque? muitos sites são dinamicos e as tags nem sempre contem um caminho fixo.

---

## CSS-selector

você usa inconscientemente , como o nome já diz **ele filtra qualquer tag por uma classe especifica**, algumas bibliotecas de scrapy conseguem filtrar por **style**.

---

## TAG-selector

Este você já usa, assim como **CSS-selector** a diferença é que este **filtra uma tag especifica INDEPENDETE de seus atributos, classes, estilos**

---

## ATRIBUTE-selector

Este provavelmente vai resolver seu problema o **ATRIBUTE-selector** é semelhante ao **TAG-selector** ou **CSS-selector** a diferença é que **ele filtra qualquer tag que usa um atributo especifico.** Como assim ?

imagine que temos um xml:

*< pessoa **feminino** > Maria < / pessoa>*

*< pessoa **masculino** > Pedro < / pessoa>*

Observe que temos o **sexo como um atributo** é diferente de

*< pessoa **sexo="masculino"** > Pedro < / pessoa >*

**Você pode usar este tipo de seleção, afinal você quer tags span que contenham o atributo class independe se class tem valor.**

Se não me engano no python podemos implementar assim. Você vai fazer um for e percorrer todos os span encontrados então você filtra por:

```
`tag.has_attr('class')`
```

---

## DOM Elements

O DOM elements incorpora tudo que já vimos até agora, porém ele tem outras funções bacanas como a manipulação do html no site, com o DOM elements conseguimos pegar as tags que pertencem a uma  tag especifica.

---

Referencias :

- BeautifulSoup = https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
- Livro Web Scraping Com Python , Editora O'Reilly
- html - DOM = https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Estou na mesma labuta. O seu script inicial está indo na direção correta, mas existem duas URLs. Uma de login e outra de pesquisa. Talvez seja necessário atribuir os dois.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
from time import sleep

URLA = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/open.do'
URLB = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/sajcas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fesaj.tjsp.jus.br%2Fesaj%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check'

user = 'x0x0x0x0x0x0x'
password ='x0x0x0x0x0x0x'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URLB)

browser.find_element_by_id('login').click()
browser.find_element_by_name('user').send_keys(user)
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id('Enviar').click()

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(URLA)

browser.find_element_by_id('NUMB').send_keys('1009238445480')
browser.find_element_by_id('Enviar_').click()

scrap = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

processo = scrap.find('span', {'class':' '' '})

print(processo)
```

Ainda não testei.